# How to add the contents of two rows in a matrix with dplyr

Tags: r, combinations, dplyr, summarization

I am trying to set up a data frame to run an ordination on. I previously grouped the data by date and then by pond, so this is how it is set up so far:

```
mydata = 
Date    Pond     Species 1   Species 2    Species 3   
1/2/3   1        0           0            1 
1/2/3   1        1           0            0 
1/2/3   1        1           1            1
1/2/3   2        0           3            1
1/2/3   2        0           1            0 
1/2/3   3        2           0            4 
1/2/3   3        1           0            1
```

I want to combine the rows so that each pond on each day is represented by one total for each species in each pond. I have tried using dplyr "summarise" function as,

```
summarise(mydata, species1 = sum(species1))
```

and I get the error,

```
"Error: unexpected symbol in: mydata"
```

Is there anyway I can combine these rows?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

1. Group your data by date and then by pond

   ```
   grp <- group_by(mydata, Date, Pond)
   ```

The `group_by` function groups a data frame by one or more variables.

2. Summarise the rows for each pond per day

   ```
    summary <- summarise(grp, Species1 = sum(Species 1), Species2 = sum(Species 2), Species3 = sum(Species3))
   ```

The `summarise` function combines multiple values into a single value.

Comment: That's exactly what I type for summarise and the error reads "Error: unexpected symbol in: mydata"